# Single Character recognition Competitive Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm working on an assignement: I've to build a letter recognition script in Matlab

I've extracted 44 features from the letters I've in input (26 different letters) and I wish to use a competitive neural network

I've a 44x26 Feature matrix  one row for each letter and I'm trying to build a net that could classify the letters in 26 different classes, without success :(

Each letter's set of feature differs from the others, so I think that stomething is wrong with te training params

here's the code for the net training:

```
epochs = 1500;
kohonen_weights_learning_rate = 0.02;
conscience_bias_learning_rate = 0.001;

net = competlayer(26, kohonen_weights_learning_rate, conscience_bias_learning_rate);
net.trainParam.epochs = epochs;
net = train(net, Features);
outputs = net(Features);
classes = vec2ind(outputs);
```

the problem is that "classes" doesn't contain 26 different classes, but usually one or two repeated classes

how could I set my net in order to make it fit the 26 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the network when trained distinguishes less classes than the designated number of classes for the given dataset (Features). It simply says that you training was not successful.

The code is correct.

You should try playing with the parameters and the epochs, until the network is trained according to your liking.

Finally, if you can't achieve to train a network that correctly recognises the classes, you should consider reviewing how you extract the features.

Comment: Maybe I'm using a wrong way to extract a character Feature. What are the common ways of extracting it?

Comment: That's a different question. Usually, in NNs the character images are fed as arrays into the neural network. I would suggest to look at cascade NNs, but I believe that this is a bit of an overkill for your application an knowledge of the matter.